# How to refactor a large class that stores numerous SqlCommands in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, architecture, refactoring, data-access-layer, legacy-code

I have recently started refactoring an old system designed by someone with little experience in OOP. Thankfully, (nearly) all access to the database are within a single 3000 lines long file. That files contains a `Dictionary<string, SqlCommand>`, the `SqlConnection`, a very long function adding every single SQL query to the dictionary like this:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(null, _sqlConnection);
cmd.CommanText = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.UserID = @id;" // Most queries are far from being this simple
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 0));
cmd.Prepare();

_cmds.Add("getUser", cmd);
```

Those queries are used by functions within that same file that would look like this:

```
public void deleteUser(int userId) 
{
    if (_cmds.TryGetValue("deleteUser", out SqlCommand cmd)) 
    {
        lock(cmd) 
        { 
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

public int isConnected(int userId, out int amount) 
{
    bool result = false;
    amount = 0;

    if (_cmds.TryGetValue("userInfo", out SqlCommand cmd)) 
    {
        lock (cmd) 
        {
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = new cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                 if (reader.HasRows)
                     while (reader.Read()) 
                     {
                         amount = (int)Math.Round(reader.GetDecimal(0));
                         result = reader.GetInt32(1);
                     }
            }
        }
    }


  return result;
}
```

Now this is horrible to work with and maintain. I finally have the time to refactor this. I wanted to turn this into a proper DAL with repositories which would be used by services and be dependency injectable.

I don't really care to change the functions or the queries (using a ORM for example). What I'm more interested in is to split the file into many files in a way that would allow me to mock, test and modify it more easily. I'm looking for a way to better structure the existing code, though I know a lot of copy/pasting and recoding will be required.

Comment: Are you planning to use an ORM like Entity framework or Nhibernate? or just ADO.net?

Comment: I would love to, but considering the amount of queries remaking them all with an Object-Relational Mapper seems impossible. I'm mostly looking for a structure which would get me on the way towards a good DAL.

Comment: I don't see any way to avoid lots of painful copying and pasting, but I can imagine how I would make it go faster. That would involve grouping certain repetitive processes like moving the SQL from the function from where it's declared now into the function where it's used. I'd copy and past `using(var command = new SqlCommand("x", connection))` into each function. Then go through the step of copying each query into the function. Paste some repetitive code to create/open the connect (or a function) and then move the parts that operate on the commands into that.

Comment: I'm estimating 100 queries. If you get it down to a few minutes per query it's a day or so of moving code around, which gets you to a class with functions just like the ones you have. That class can be a repository with an injected SQL connection string, and then you can extract an interface from it and inject that. It wouldn't arrive at an ideal state, but it would be at least somewhat refactored, have the same methods, and not do weird stuff like storing what looks like an open SQL connection.

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend replacing the manually written object-mapping code with using an Object-Relational Mapper like **[NHibernate](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core)**, which will save the time and effort of creating and maintaining a data access layer.

Comment: The problem with that is that I would have to remake 2000 lines worth of queries I don't even understand as well as changing a lot of code in the services.

Comment: I understand. It is worth checking how many of these queries are standard selects and how many are more specific. All in all, changing to an ORM might be the most time-saving solution of all. I can't imagine a quick solution

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). It is a "micro-ORM" and offers high-performance object-oriented data access. You can continue to use all the existing queries, but replace all the boiler-plate ADO.NET code with Dapper.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to take some repetitive work, but here are a few ideas on how to get a handle on it. This won't put the code in some ideal state, but might make it a little bit more manageable. One challenge is that every method has parts in two places - one in the method and one where the command is stored in the dictionary.

- Don't add any more SQL to this class, ever. Begin defining and using the new repositories you want.
- Being able to mock it is easy, too. You can use the [extract interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-interface?view=vs-2019) refactoring to create an interface so that you can mock this class, even in its current form. That's going to be a big, ugly interface, but at least you can mock methods if you need to.

That's the easy part. How can the entire class be refactored without breaking any one part of it? These steps are just some ideas:

A first step is just to inject the connection string the class needs:

```
public class YourDataAccessClass
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public YourDataAccessClass(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

You'll use it one method at a time. Initially you can leave most of the class, including the dictionary, as-is. That way the methods you haven't modified will continue to work.

Next, you could open up the class in two separate windows so that you can see the dictionary function that contains the SQL and the functions that use it side-by-side. This will be a lot harder if you have to scroll back up and down.

You'll likely want to move the SQL for each function into that function. You could do this as you refactor each function, but it might be less painful to do it all at once so that you gain efficiency from repetition.

You could define a new variable in each function and copy and paste:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.UserID = @id;";
```

(Again, not the way I'd normally write this.)

Now you've got a function or 100 functions that look like this:

```
public void deleteUser(int userId) 
{
    var sql = "DELETE User WHERE User.UserID = @id;";
    if (_cmds.TryGetValue("deleteUser", out SqlCommand cmd)) 
    {
        lock(cmd) 
        { 
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

For the non-query commands you could write a function like this in your class which will eliminate the repetitive code to open a connection, create a command, etc:

```
private void ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, Action<SqlCommand> addParameters = null)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql))
    {
        addParameters?.Invoke(command);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Save the following snippet of code. You might even just be able to keep it in the clipboard most of the time. Paste it into each one of your non-query methods right beneath the SQL:

```
ExecuteNonQuery(sql, command =>
{

});
```

After you paste it, move the line or lines that add parameters into the body of the `cmd` argument (which is named `cmd` so that you can move the lines without changing the variable name) and then delete the existing code that executed the query previously.

```
ExecuteNonQuery(sql, cmd =>
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;
});
```

Now your function looks like this:

```
public void deleteUser(int userId) 
{
    var sql = "DELETE User WHERE User.UserID = @id;";
    ExecuteNonQuery(sql, cmd =>
    {
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;
    });
}
```

I'm not saying that's fun, but it will make the process of editing those functions more efficient since you're typing less and just moving things around in exactly the same way over and over.

The ones that actually return data are less fun, but still manageable.

First, take pretty much the same boilerplate code. This could likely be improved because it's still a little repetitive, but at least it's more self-contained:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql)) // again, named "cmd" on purpose
{

    connection.Open();        

}
```

Starting with this:

```
public int isConnected(int userId, out int name) 
{
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.UserID = @id;";'
    bool result = false;
    amount = 0;

    if (_cmds.TryGetValue("userInfo", out SqlCommand cmd)) 
    {
        lock (cmd) 
        {
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = new cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                 if (reader.HasRows)
                     while (reader.Read()) 
                     {
                         amount = (int)Math.Round(reader.GetDecimal(0));
                         result = reader.GetInt32(1);
                     }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Paste your boilerplate into the method:

```
public int isConnected(int userId, out int name) 
{
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.UserID = @id;";'
    bool result = false;
    amount = 0;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql)) // again, named "cmd" on purpose
    {

        connection.Open();        

    }

    if (_cmds.TryGetValue("userInfo", out SqlCommand cmd)) 
    {
        lock (cmd) 
        {
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;

            using (SqlDataReader reader = new cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                 if (reader.HasRows)
                     while (reader.Read()) 
                     {
                         amount = (int)Math.Round(reader.GetDecimal(0));
                         result = reader.GetInt32(1);
                         // was this a typo? The code in the question doesn't
                         // return anything or set the "out" variable. But
                         // if that's in the method then that will be part of
                         // what gets copied.
                     }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, just like before, move the part where you add your parameters above `connection.Open();` and move the part where you use the command just beneath `connection.Open();` and delete what's left. The result is this:

```
public int isConnected(int userId, out int name) 
{
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.UserID = @id;";'
    bool result = false;
    amount = 0;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql)) // again, named "cmd" on purpose
    {
        cmd.Parameters[0].Value = userId;
        connection.Open();        
        using (SqlDataReader reader = new cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
             if (reader.HasRows)
                 while (reader.Read()) 
                 {
                     amount = (int)Math.Round(reader.GetDecimal(0));
                     result = reader.GetInt32(1);
                 }
        }
    }
}
```

You can probably get into a groove and do these in a minute or two each, which means that it will only take a few hours.

Once all of this is done you can delete your massive dictionary function. Now the class depends on an injected connection string and opens and closes connections normally instead of storing a connection and using it over and over.

You can also break it up. One way is to move the connection string and the helper function into a base class (or just duplicate the helper function - it's really small) and you can move any of the query functions into a smaller class because each function is self-contained.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the methods I'll definitely head in this direction. One slight hitch, of course, the sql commands and functions are not 1 to 1, some sql commands are used in multiple functions and some functions use multiple commands (I don't even know what some of those do)

Comment: I'd love to hear how this goes. It's so satisfying to take something big and unmanageable and bend it to your will. Everyone wants to write good new code, but fixing difficult code is righteous.